# Change div content while scrolling using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, image, scroll, fixed

I have a fixed div box on the right, and I want to make it so that as the page scrolls, the content in the box changes according to the content on the left that corresponds to it using I need some help because I don't know how to do this using jQuery.

Here is an example animation of what I mean:
[image: [Example]()]

Comment: Did you even try anything? No code, can't help :/

Comment: Well I have the HTML/CSS code. I just don't know how to implement it using jQuery. 

This is kind of what inspired me:
http://goratchet.com/components/

Comment: That's where you get started — put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), search SO or Google for possible tricks. I'm sure a few keywords can get you started. SO is not the place to ask for people to write code for you — showing some effort, no matter how infinitesimal, is also showing that you respect the time of those who are trying to help.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I understand. I've been searching around but the keywords I have been using regarding scrolling and jQuery has been taking me something completely different. Can you suggest maybe an event in jQuery or something that can help guide me into the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question shows *very little* by the way of effort, but just to get you *started*, you could use [Bootstrap Scrollspy](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) and then hide any links without the `active` class.

If this doesn't meet your needs, please use this as a starting point to ask a more focused question in the future.

## [Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/U7d2y/)

1. First, setup all of your section headers as list items like this:

   ```html
   <div id="sidebar">
       <ul class="nav">
           <li><a href="#Content1">Content 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#Content2">Content 2</a></li>
           <li><a href="#Content3">Content 3</a></li>
       </ul>
       Lorem Ipsum
   </div>
   ```
2. Then add scrollspy to the page, targeting the `#sidebar` you just created

   ```js
   $('body').scrollspy({ target: '#sidebar' })
   ```
3. Then style all `li`s as hidden, but override the active one to make it visible:

   ```css
   #sidebar li        { display: none;  }
   #sidebar li.active { display: block; }
   ```

#### Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by listening to the jQuery scroll event.

When the scroll is triggered it should check if the current scroll position is equal to the position where you want the change to happen.

Comment: Your answer seems to be **too broad for the OP's needs**. Consider giving more details on what should they do.